# C# - Como verificar se um campo do tipo string está vazio e encerrar o código

Tags: c#

Estou tendo dificuldades em verificar se o campo do tipo `string` não foi preenchido, é exatamente nesse trecho.

```
Write("Digite o nome do usuário: ");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReadLine())) return;
j1.setNome(ReadLine());
Write($"Digite o nome do stand de {j1.getNome()}: ");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReadLine())) return;
j1.setStand(ReadLine());
```

- Código completo

```
using static System.Console;

public class JoJo {

        private string nome, stand;
        private bool status_stand = false;
        
        public string getNome() { return nome; }
        public string getStand() { return stand; }
        public bool getStatusStand() { return status_stand; }
        public void setNome(string nome) { this.nome = nome; }
        public void setStand(string stand) { this.stand = stand; }
        public void setStatusStand(bool status_stand) { this.status_stand = status_stand; }

        public void ativarStand() {
            if (this.getStatusStand()) {
                WriteLine($"{this.getStand()} já está invocado.");
            }
            else {
                this.setStatusStand(true);
                WriteLine($"{this.getStand()} foi invocado.");
            }
        }

        public void desativarStand() {
            if (this.getStatusStand() == false) {
                WriteLine($"{this.getStand()} já está oculto.");
            }
            else {
                this.setStatusStand(false);
                WriteLine($"{this.getStand()} foi ocultado.");
            }
        }

        public void interacao() {
            string resultado;
            WriteLine($"Nome: {this.getNome()}");
            WriteLine($"Stand: {this.getStand()}");
            resultado = this.getStatusStand() ? "Ativo." : "Inativo.";
            WriteLine($"Status do stand: {resultado}");
            if (this.getStatusStand()) {
                ativarStand();
            }
            else {
                desativarStand();
            }
        }
    }

class Program {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
     JoJo j1 = new JoJo();
     Write("Digite o nome do usuário: ");
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReadLine())) return;
     j1.setNome(ReadLine());
     Write($"Digite o nome do stand de {j1.getNome()}: ");
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReadLine())) return;
     j1.setStand(ReadLine());
     Write("\n");
     j1.interacao();
    ReadKey();
  }
}
```

Comment: pq usar `ReadLine` duas vezes? atribui a uma variável e faz tudo com ela... `var entrada = ReadLine(); if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entrar) ......  j1.setNome(entrada)`  outra coisa, esse código de getNome, setNome é coisa de `Java` não se usa isso em `C#` simplesmente faz `public string Nome { get; set; }` e depois `Nome = entrada`, sugiro estudar `C#` esse código está muito "fora do padrão" de como costumar ser um código em `C#`

Answer (score -1):

Você está chamando a função `ReadLine` duas vezes, o que implica que a entrada terá duas linhas.

```cs
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReadLine())) return;
j1.setNome(ReadLine());
```

Cada vez que a função `ReadLine()` é chamada, ela espera um input, e se você não armazena isso em algum lugar, esse input é perdido. Ele só seria usado para a linha onde você chamou a função e depois não mais. Se sua entrada para o nome for, por exemplo:

```
daniel
daniel
```

... isso daria certo, mas como creio que não é o caso, seria melhor você chamar a função uma vez e armazenar em uma variável, depois usar essa variável para fazer a comparação.